# How to show messageBox with InstallShield 2009

Tags: c#, java, installation, installshield, messagebox

I'd like to show a messageBox in the setup.

Have how to put this messageBox into a Custom Action? 
Because I want to this messageBox appears when one condition is satisfied.

If isn't clear, please, let me know!

**EDIT**:

I want to make a script to verify if the .exe that I'm trying to execute it's already installed, if don't --> execute, else --> do nothing.

Comment: Be warned - MessageBoxes do not play nicely with unattended setups. You should make sure it's only shown when the installer UI is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for warn. But I want to this messageBox appears before the setup ends.

Comment: "MessageBox" is an antipattern in the windows installer world.  You should be using MSI dialogs launched with a SpawnDialog control event.

Comment: I just want to: when I click in a button, the program will verify one condition and if true, show a message.

Comment: Please see the edit area to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an InstallScript function, there you have a MessageBox().

Comment: I'm new using InstallShield, how do I do this?

Comment: See this example: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/mergedProjects/installshield18langref/LangrefMessageBox_example.htm

Comment: Now I have to know how to execute this code. Sorry duplicate comments.

Comment: OK, I found how to use the function. But, I need to use it in a 'Exe' custom action. Have how to?

Comment: Example (different technique, just follow until you can go on with first idea or use this...as you prefer): http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/IHelpDLLFunctionStdEx.htm

Comment: Is the exe you do not want to overwrite part of the application or it's the application by itself? Anyway I guess you should manage this using its properties in the installation, not by hand.

Comment: If it's just a single file you may use the **Always Overwrite** property.

Comment: I want to execute an application different of the setup's application. But before execute it, I need to verify if this second setup is already installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8936/discussion-between-leonardo-arruda-and-adriano)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is w.r.t. Installshield 2014 but it is quite common use case to show an error message box during installation based on certain condition. So, this solution might help someone even in case you want to achieve it in an installshield version higher than Installshield 2009.

I achieved it through `SpawnDialog` control event as discussed below. Let's say you have a dialog with `<Back`, `Next>` and `Cancel` buttons. On the click of `Next>` button you want to make some check e.g. whether a service is up and running or not.

If service is down then you might want to show an error dialog popup instead of moving to the next wizard step. So this is how you setup your `Next>` button behavior as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

Now you can notice the `SpawnDialog` event. I've set it to `SetupErrorNew`. What is `SetupErrorNew`? `SetupErrorNew` is also a dialog. I created it by cloning pre-existing `SetupError` dialog template as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]

This dialog will show the error message that you desire. Few key things that we need to set on the new error message dialog `SetupErrorNew` as below:

1. Set the `Error Dialog` property of the dialog to `False`.
2. Error dialog has a number of buttons for Yes, No, Ok, Cancel, Retry, Abort, Ignore options. Delete all buttons except Ok button.
3. Set the appropriate error message text.
4. Under Behavior -> For Ok button change the `argument` value of `EndDialog` event to `Return` as shown in the snapshot below:

[image]